# Facebook friends - Will my friend(who was retrieved with lower api version of me/friends) get app scoped user id if he/she connects my app with 2.x?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We had fetched friend's data prior april changes of facebook, where me/friends returned the actual user ids of all of my friends. Even today if I query for my id it would return me the actual user id and not the app scoped id as I was previously connected to the app.

My question is if my friend connects this app today. Will he be getting the new app scoped id or the actual fb user id as previously received in my friendlist?

Comment: App scoped. Whether you get an app scoped user id, or the global one, depends on when the user logged in to your app for the first time. If that was after API v2 was introduced, then you get their app-scoped user id.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your answer. How could you figure out if this is the same person? As the id previously stored(friend's user id) will be different than what you got now(app scoped). And there is no way to get user id from app scoped id.

Comment: _“How could you figure out if this is the same person?”_ – you can’t. What would you need that for anyway? `/me/friends` now only returns friends that are users of the same app as well already – and that’s what your app should work with, and not any “stored” lists of friends that have nothing to do with your app.

Comment: Ok. One more question that I have. If someone doesn't use fb connect plugin on our site, but just likes some post or our app on facebook page. would we get that friend in the list?  Or are these the friends who connects using our site's fbconnect feature?

Comment: No, commenting or liking on a page does not make someone a user of your app. They have to login to your app and grant the `user_friends` permission – only then your app will be able to see them as friends of another user X (that also gave the app the same permission.)

Comment: Thanks for all the clarifications. You can post our comment as an answer instead that I can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you get an app scoped user id, or the global one, depends on when the user logged in to your app for the first time. If that was after API v2 was introduced, then you get their app-scoped user id.

You can not figure out if a new user that logs in to your app for the first time now (and will get an app-scoped user id) is identical to a user whose global id you got long time ago by reading someone’s friend list.

Your app will only be able to “see” friends of the current user now, if they are users of the app as well, and have granted `user_friends` permission as well.